# How to declare a LOOKUP CHANNEL for django user model in django ajax-selects

Tags: ajax, django, autocomplete, django-templates

I am using [django-postman](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/wiki/Home) to provide user-to-user message facility and this uses django [ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) to provide `autocomplete` facility for usernames when sending a message. I need to declare a channel for Django user and pass it to the `postman` application. Here how it has to be done. I declare a channel as shown below and

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    #   pass a dict with the model and the field to search against
    'user'  : {'model':'django.contrib.auth.User', 'search_field':'username'},
}
```

here I pass it to the `postman` app

```
POSTMAN_AUTOCOMPLETER_APP = {
        'name': 'ajax_select', 
        'field': 'AutoCompleteField',
        'arg_name': 'channel', 
        'arg_default': 'user', # no default, mandatory to enable the feature
    }
```

But when I do this I get a `template syntax error` as `Caught ValueError while rendering: too many values to unpack`

Can anybody help me know whats really happening here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'user'  : {'model': 'auth.user', 'search_field': 'username'},
}
```

changing `'django.contrib.auth.User'` to `'auth.user'`